# I am using smartsvn 6.6 on mac os x,Is it necessary to upload a repository on Apache site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, svn, tortoisesvn, smartsvn

Actually I want to put the repository on the local path.
Which protocol I should use.
Everytime I am getting an error for connection to path is not working.
Help me please.
I am very new to the Smart Svn.
Can Anybody provide me a good tutorial site on Smartsvn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SmartSVN does not support the *file://*-protocol, however you may use the *svn://*-protocol in combination with a local *svnserve*-process as an alternative. Refer to [SmartSVN Manual - Set Up Local Repository](http://www.syntevo.com/smartsvn/documentation.html?page=commands.repository-setup) for details.